# How do I get CKEditor to work for inline editing

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, inline-editing

I want to use CKEditor to edit pages on my site.  The inline editing feature looks cool however I can't get it to work.

I copied the example on their website to one of my pages and i can edit the text but the CKEditor doesn't appear?  There are no errors in the console.

What is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out after a bit of research on the CKEditor website that CKEditor has a restricted set of Tags that it will pop up on.  You can see the [list here on the CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable object](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd)

By default it only will pop up on the following tags

```
{address: 1, article: 1, aside: 1, blockquote: 1, body: 1, details: 1, 
div: 1, fieldset: 1, figcaption: 1, footer: 1, form: 1, 
h1: 1, h2: 1, h3: 1, h4: 1, h5: 1, h6: 1, header: 1, hgroup: 1, main: 1,
nav: 1, p: 1, pre: 1, section: 1}
```

I was using `<span>` so it wasn't working.  Changed it to `<div>` and it worked.